# Outlook Web Add-in: how to redirect to other page?

Tags: javascript, redirect, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm currently working on an outlook web add-in with login and some other pages. The flow would be a user should first log in and once they are successfully logged in the Add-in should redirect to a home page. So currently I'm using the `window.location.href` to redirect to a different page.

```
if (authenticated) {
      window.location.href = '/home/home.html';
}
```

However, when I'm in the home page and click a button that will redirect again to different page an error occurs. When I checked the console for the location it became `https://localhost:44320/home/foo/foo.html` instead of `https://localhost:44320/foo/foo.html`. I know I can just assigned the whole url but I want it to be shorter by just calling the page (foo/foo.html).

My question are what would be the proper/best approach on this and is there any different ways on doing this -- redirecting Add-in to different page?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `location.pathname = '/home/home.html'` to solve it

or generate full url with

`var fullUrl = location .protocol + "//" + location.host + "/home/home.html"`